# Habilitar e desabilitar um botão

Tags: html, css, script

pessoal.

Eu estou desenvolvendo um formulário com alguns inputs/campos obrigatórios, e abaixo dos campos, há um botão, cujo destino/ação dado(a) a ele seja somente liberada caso os campos estiverem preenchidos. Eu gostaria de fazer a seguinte coisa:

Se os inputs/campos ainda não estivessem preenchidos, o botão ficasse desabilitado, fazendo com que o usuário não possa clicar e navegar para o destino/ação dado(a) ao botão. E assim que os inputs fossem preenchidos, o botão ficasse habilitado, permitindo o clique do usuário.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" class="ultimo"/>
  <button disabled class="meu-botao">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input
{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  height:30px;
}

.valido
{
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

A primeira coisa a ser feita é validar se todos os campos foram preenchidos, que pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){
    if(this.value != ''){
      this.classList.add('valido');
    }
  });
}
```

Após validar se todos os campos foram preenchidos você deve habilitar o botão quando um dos campos perder o foco através da função `addEventListener()`.

Podemos habilitar o botão por exemplo quando o ultimo campo perder o foco **e** o todo o formulario estiver validado. Segue o exemplo:

```
document.querySelector('.ultimo').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  if(formularioValido()){
    document.querySelector('.meu-botao').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

A função `formularioValido()` serve para verificar se todos os campos foram corretamente preenchidos.

```
var formularioValido = function(){
  var inputsValidos = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input[i].classList.contains('valido')){
      inputsValidos++;
    }
  }

  if(inputsValidos == input.length) return true;
  else return false;
};
```

Há diversas melhorias que podem ser feitas nesse código. Use-o como exemplo para criar o que melhor se adapta a sua situação. Fiz um exemplo no `codepen`. Você pode ver nesse [link aqui](https://codepen.io/cleiton/pen/rrrzoX?editors=1111)

Sucesso (+